# How are zero-length arrays in a structure useful?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

Quoting from [this site](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html),

> Zero-length arrays are allowed in GNU C. They are very useful as the last element of a structure that is really a header for a variable-length object.

Code:

```
 struct line {
   int length;
   char contents[0];
 };

 struct line *thisline = (struct line *)malloc(sizeof (struct line) + this_length);
 thisline->length = this_length;
```

I really did not understand what they have meant by this: "last element of a structure that is really a header for a variable-length object". Can someone elaborate on that sentence?

Comment: I thought normally you answer questions not the other way around :D (p.s. good question)

Comment: A header is a thing that is at the beginning of something. You have a variable amount of memory that you allocate dynamically; at the beginning of it are your normal struct fields (the header), and the remainder of the memory is the array.

Comment: The thing is that you can `malloc` more space than just `struct line`, and then, using the fact that memory returned by `malloc` is contiguous, refer to that extra space via `thisline->contents[i]`.

Comment: @KerrekSB , So I can use `contents` as if it were a member of the structure having size `this_length`?

Comment: @CoolGuy Yes, that's exactly how it works.

Comment: [Do not cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zero-length arrays (which have been replaced with *flexible array members* in C99) let you allocate structures with variable size in a single allocation instead of two allocations. Without flexible array members you would be forced to do this:

```
struct line {
   int length;
   char *contents;
};

struct line *thisline = malloc(sizeof (struct line));
thisline->length = this_length;
thisline->contents=malloc(this_length);
```

Flexible array member saves you from making the second allocation, and also from having to call `free` a second time.

In addition to its convenience, this little trick helps you save on memory overhead. Each time you allocate a block of memory, `malloc` needs to store some "bookkeeping" information for the use of `free`. In addition, the blocks the `malloc` allocates are sized at specific increments, leaving small unused portions at the end of each block. By reducing the number of allocations in half you can reduce the overhead by a significant fraction.

Answer (score 3):

It is old C. With current [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) or [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) standard you can use *flexible array members* (which should be the last member of a `struct`) like:

```
struct line {
  unsigned length;
  char contents[];
};
```

and you need a convention about the occupied size of the flexible array. If `contents` is a C string (like we all expect), you could suppose its size is `length+1` (since you need a terminating null byte). Then you should comment that.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19748900/841108) & [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18485347/841108)

Answer (score 1):

> I really did not understand what they have meant by this: "last element of a structure that is really a header for a variable-length object".

It means this is OK (in GNU C):

```
 struct line {
   int length;
   char contents[0];  // OK, last member of the structure
 };
```

but this is not:

```
 struct line {
   char contents[0];  // Wrong, not the last member of the structure
   int length;
 };
```